# How to create a internal store for android applications

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play

I am planning to develop a internal store for android applications,where only people within the organisation should be able to access the applications

Users will be given access to a private URL , clicking on that URL and accepting the permission from user , The app should automatically download and install on user device

Can i please know what would be the best idea to distribute android apps within the enterprise without hosting it on Google private play store .

Answer (score 0):

upload your .apk file on your organization/any server and then you can make a link to download the .apk thats it....This is what everyone doing for users testing before uploading it to GooglePlay.... :) :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, The problem is if users download the apk from server , Its sits in his downloads folder, Then he can easily share that apk to any other person outside the organisation , How can we prevent this?

Comment: You can't.  Even apps installed from the Play Store can be copied and shared.